# Intuition for scale of the largest eigenvalue of symmetric Gaussian matrix

Tags: probability, intuition

Let $X$ be $n \times n$ matrix whose matrix elements are independent identically distributed normal variables with zero mean and variance of $\frac{1}{2}$. Then
$$
     A = \frac{1}{2} \left(X + X^\top\right)
$$
is a [random matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_matrix) from GOE ensemble with weight $\exp(-\operatorname{Tr}(A^2))$. Let $\lambda_\max(n)$ denote its largest eigenvalue. The soft edge limit asserts convergence of $\left(\lambda_\max(n)-\sqrt{n}\right) n^{1/6}$ in distribution as $n$ increases.

> Q: I am seeking to get an intuition (or better yet, a simple argument) for why the largest eigenvalue scales like $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a Frobenius norm squared of $A$:
$$
   \|A\|^2 = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}^2 = 2 \sum_{i<j}a_{i,j}^2 + \sum_{i} a_{ii}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2
$$
The expected value of $\|A\|^2$ is easy to find:
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left( \|A\|^2 \right) = 2 \sum_{i<j} \mathbb{E}\left(a_{i,j}^2\right) + \sum_{i} \mathbb{E}\left( a_{ii}^2 \right) = 2 \sum_{i<j} \frac{1}{4} + \sum_{i} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{4} < n \mathbb{E}\left(\lambda_\max(n)^2\right)
$$
this establishes $\lambda_\max(n)$ scales  at least as $\sqrt{n}$

Answer (score 4):

The scaling follows from the Wigner semicircle law. Proof of the Wigner semicircle law is outlined in section 2.5 of the review "[Orthogonal polynomials ensembles in probability theory](http://www.i-journals.org/ps/viewarticle.php?id=44)" by W. König, Probability Surveys, vol. 2 (2005), pp. 385-447.