# What is the maximum expected eigenvalue of an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices, spectral-radius

> Given an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix filled with realizations of a *uniform* random variable taking values in $[-1, 1]$, determine the maximum expected eigenvalue using analytic methods.

Running multiple MATLAB scripts of a large $n$ matrix gave me a the following plot:

[image: histogram]

Observe, the elliptic nature of the $100 \times 100$ plot. Intuitively, I suspect the maximum value of the eigenvalues must be $\sqrt{n}$, but I don't know how to determine this value analytically (or even if $\sqrt{n} $ is indeed true).

I've attempted reading *Pastur et Al.*'s ["Eigenvalue distribution for Large Random matrices"](https://www.ams.org/books/surv/171/surv171-endmatter.pdf) But can't make sense of their work.

**In short** What is the relationship between $n$, dimension of the matrix and the maximum expected eigenvalue?

Comment: The question "what is the maximum eigenvalue for a matrix with entries in $[-1,1]$" has nothing to do with randomness. [For instance, the all $1$s matrix has $n$ as an eigenvalue.] Is this the question you want to ask, or are you asking for the expected maximum eigenvalue (where the randomness comes from the entries being uniformly chosen from $[-1,1]$)?

Comment: @angryavian I'm referring to the relationship between the dimension $n$ and the maximum expected eigenvalue if the entries of the matrix were uniformly random from $[-1, 1] $

Comment: There is no mention of "expected value" in your question. You should probably edit that in, as readers shouldn't be expected to read the comments to make sense of your question.

Comment: The key terms seem to be "Bernoulli matrix ensemble" and "Wigner's semicircle law", but I don't know much more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Correct solution is $n$ opposed to my original intuition of $\sqrt{n}$

**For the positive case only**

*Proof*

Observe that 
$$ tr(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{ii} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lambda_i $$

Meaning that the sum of the diagonals is simultaneously equal to the sum of the possible eigenvalues in any square matrix.

Now, let $m$ be the largest entry into A (*ie*. For our case $m = 1$ as all $a_{ij}$ normally randomly chosen $ \in [-1, 1]$

Let $$\lambda _{max} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \lambda _k = tr(A)$$
$$\implies \lambda _{max} \leq tr(A)$$
$$a_{ii} \leq m$$ 
Every $a_{ij}$ entry is less than the maximum

$$\implies \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{ii} \leq \sum_{i = 1}^{n} m$$
$$\implies tr(A) \leq mn$$
$$\lambda _{max} \leq tr(A) \leq mn$$
$$\lambda _{max} \leq mn$$
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Special thanks to Rahul (in comments) & Raghav Srinivasan of the University of Toronto.

Alternately, observe that intuitively I thought that $\sqrt{n}$ was the correct solution because in a Wigner distribution, the scaling as $n \to \infty$ is $\sqrt{n}$ This can be [proven here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300894/intuition-for-scale-of-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-symmetric-gaussian-matrix/301809#301809)